Getting class from interface static method
I have following code:
public interface IEnum {

    static <E extends Enum<E> & IEnum> Map<Integer, E> getId2EnumMap(Class<E> clazz) {
        Map<Integer, E> temp = new HashMap<>();
        for (final E e : clazz.getEnumConstants()) {
            temp.put(e.getId(), e);
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(temp);
    }

    int getId();
}

public enum TestEnum2 implements IEnum {
    ONE(1),
    TWOOOOOOO(22);

    public final Integer id;

    TestEnum2(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    static final Map<Integer, TestEnum2> enumToId;
    static {
        enumToId = IEnum.getId2EnumMap(TestEnum2.class);
    }

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

In this code, all I want to do is not have to pass TestEnum2.class to IEnum.getId2EnumMap. Is it possible either by modification of interface signature or some other way?
I have tried multiple threads from Stack Overflow, but every single one of them result in either of two things:

Interface Function cannot be static which results in not being able to call it in TestEnum2 in static block

It can be static but since method is interface method is static, I cannot get concrete type



During compiling all generics are erased. That means that the resulting signature is static Map getId2EnumMap(Class clazz). If the signature before erasure would be static <E extends Enum<E> & IEnum> Map<Integer, E> getId2EnumMap(), during runtime there would be nothing left to identify the type (note that C# which doesn't use erasure and does allow you to read the generic type during runtime). In other words, you need something to be able to get the constants. I see two options:

Do what you do now.
Replace Class<E> clazz with E[] constants and getEnumConstants() with constants. The call would become IEnum.getId2EnumMap(values()).


Note that you can make the method a bit easier to read (at least, that's what I think):
static <E extends Enum<E> & IEnum> Map<Integer, E> getId2EnumMap(Class<E> clazz) {
    return Arrays.stream(clazz.getEnumConstants())
            .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableMap(IEnum::getId, Function.identity()));
}


One final remark: you can get rid of the static initializer block by assigning the value directly:
static final Map<Integer, TestEnum2> enumToId = IEnum.getId2EnumMap(TestEnum2.class);


Edit: there is one way to base this on the current class, using StackWalker:
public interface IEnum {

    static <E extends Enum<E> & IEnum> Map<Integer, E> getId2EnumMap() {
        StackWalker stackWalker = StackWalker.getInstance(Option.RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE);
        Class<E> clazz = (Class<E>) stackWalker.getCallerClass();
        Map<Integer, E> temp = new HashMap<>();
        for (final E e : clazz.getEnumConstants()) {
            temp.put(e.getId(), e);
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(temp);
    }

    int getId();
}

public enum TestEnum2 implements IEnum {
    ONE(1),
    TWOOOOOOO(22);

    public final Integer id;

    TestEnum2(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    static final Map<Integer, TestEnum2> enumToId = IEnum.getId2EnumMap();

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

Note however that the cast is necessary to let clazz.getEnumConstants() return E[] but it gives an unchecked cast warning. The compiler won't prevent me from doing this in a completely unrelated class:
static final Map<Integer, TestEnum2> enumToId = IEnum.getId2EnumMap();

This will compile but give a ClassCastException when you try to get values from the map. You could add some checks in getId2EnumMap to at least make sure that IEnum.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz), but I can still call the above in a different class that implements IEnum. The issue is that you cannot verify that the generic type E matches the caller class in any way in Java - because the generic type is simply gone during runtime.

I've added the closing ), but I explicitly omitted IEnum because the enum implements the interface and therefore doesn't need to call it with IEnum., like I mentioned in the node to the second option.

Thanks! With either solution by @RobSpoor or I, the problem stays - that 1. We cannot implicitly find out class thereby creating remote possibility that the type\values supplied to the function may not be from same enum 2. interface inheritance then doesn't really give any benefit.

@Rob Java Language Specification 8.4.8. Inheritance, Overriding, and Hiding: "A class does not inherit private or static methods from its superinterface types."

@user85421 you're right. It works for super classes but not super interfaces. I've added the missing IEnum.

@user1578026 I've added some extra notes on using StackWalker, but it still allows you to do stuff that you don't want. That's something that you cannot prevent because the generic type simply doesn't exist during runtime.

@RobSpoor Oh, but this version with StackWalker is much better than whatever I came up with. I cannot control who calls the method but with keeping my original signature with type parameter as <E extends Enum<E> & IEnum>, at least I can 1. guarantee it would fail for  non IEnum implementing class 2. not need clazz parameter 3. optionally, can get rid of getId() if need be (there are about 20 Enums in our code base with this pattern, each one with field "id" and duplicate map creating code. Thanks. Accepting as answer.

Since a static method, you cannot have an external reference.
You could use the default instead of static and override some parts of the method in each class that implements this interface
